how can i modify the UploadFile type of ant design Upload Component?
This is the initial state of the
fileList 

When you want to pass it to the Upload component in Ant Design, and you should use
UploadFile 

type:
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<UploadFile[]>([]);


but I have this type:
export type AddMediaPoolUploadFieldTypes = {
  uid: string;
  url: string;
  fileName: string;
  status: "done" | "error" | "uploading";
  date: Date;
  alignment: "horizontal" | "vertical" | "other";
  title: string;
  description: string;
  keywords: string;
  spot: boolean;
  bgnd: boolean;
  resolution: "other" | "HD" | "FullHD" | "4KUHD" | "8KUHD" | null;
  categoryColor: string;
  categoryName: string;`your text`
  fileSize: string;
};

and I want to use it instead of
UploadFile 

type in my code. how can I do it?
I put it my code but it didn't returns me the right outcome

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
